# Encontar valor maximo de un Array en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Necesito recorrer un Array y encontrar el valor mayor dentro de él pero sin utilizar metodos.
Yo he intentado esto pero no me funciona.

```js
var lista = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
var res = 0;
var acumulador = 0;

//function maximoValor(n){
for (let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
  console.log(lista[i])
  if (lista[i] > lista[i + 1]) {
    res = i
    console.log(res)
  }
}
```

Comment: vas bien, tienes la variable acumulador que no la usas, en vez de comparar el número de lista con el siguiente, comparalo con res, también igualalo dentro del if con el elemento de la lista, no con i

Comment: var lista = new Array(1, 2, 8, 6, 10);
  var res = 0;
  var acumulador = 0;
  //function maximoValor(n){
   for (let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
   //console.log(lista[i])
    if (lista[i] > res){
     res = lista[i];
     
     }
     
    } 
  
  console.log(res)

Comment: Con esto funciona muchisimas gracias @NicolasOñate. Me piden hacer en una funcion pero no veo el parametro a añadir en la funcion. Al final los elementos del Array ya estan dados. Hago una funcion sin parametro y la llamo sin mas?

Comment: Hola @toperon, puedes añadir como parámetro el `Array` a evaluar.

Comment: al declararar una funcion puedes pasarle parametros `function TuFuncion(var1,var2){//Tu comparador}`

Comment: var lista = new Array(1, 2, 8, 12, 10);
  
  function maximoValor(lista){
  var res = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
    if (lista[i] > res){
     res = lista[i];
     
     }
     
    }
    return res
  }    
  
  console.log(maximoValor(lista))
  
  
  Esto funciona perfecto. Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 6):

> **Nota:** lea los comentarios que se encuentra en el código.

### Comparar valores

Solo tienes que comparar los valores que se encuentran dentro del `Array`.

**Por ejemplo:**

```js
// Array de números:
const numeros = [1, 2, 3, 30, 5, 6];

// Nuestra variable auxiliar para almacenar en ella
// el valor más grande del array:
let max = 0;

// Recorres el valor del array «numeros»:
for ( let numero of numeros ) {

  // Evalúa si «max» es menor que «numero» para almacenar
  // en él el número más grande hasta el momento:
  if (max < numero)
    max = numero;
}

// Muestra en la consola el valor numérico más grande del Array:
console.log(max);
```

Solo necesitas crear una variable auxiliar (`max`, en este caso) para almacenar en ella el valor más grande del `Array`.

Answer (score -1):

Se puede hacer usando la función nativa Math.max, pero funcionará si utilizas el operador spread porque Math.max espera una lista de argumentos numéricos y no un array. Ejemplo:

let arr = [3, 5, 1];

alert(Math.max(...arr));